# What's the probability of getting a prime number by typing randomly a number which length's is 13 digits?

Tags: probability

What's the probability of getting a prime number by typing randomly a number which length's is 13 digits?

I've typed randomly **`8,564,820,310,447`** and discovered it was prime. I had only 1 try, what was the probability of getting a prime number in this case? *(13 digits long number)*

Comment: How many $13$-digit numbers are there?  How many of them are prime?

Comment: I guess you did not chose the last digit blindly. It if is $1$,$3$,$7$ or $9$, the chance to get a prime increases

Comment: I would say it is $\frac{\pi(10^{13})-\pi(10^{12})}{9\cdot10^{12}}$.

Comment: @saulspatz i'm checking it may take some minutes 
(i create a python program to check for me, because i didnt find the answer on google)

Comment: @Peter noo i litterly typed that randomly it was pure luck

Comment: @Peter thanks man !
can you tell me what's the probality ?
if you dont mind thanks <3

Comment: @user are you sure about it?

Comment: $\pi(10^{13})=346,065,536,839$ , $\pi(10^{12})=37,607,912,018$ Divide the difference by $9\cdot 10^{12}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

Comment: Your chance was about $1:29$

Comment: @Peter damn, i was really lucky then hahaha

Comment: Don't tell anyone however that you did not care for the last digit :)

Comment: @Peter i swear to god i typed that by an accident
it's also my cat who typed at the number pad